# how do I avoid case sensitivity when appending file extension to a variable

Tags: bash

I need to avoid case sensitivity when appending a '.csv' to a variable :

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
date=("$1".csv)
```

This does not seem to be working although it works here:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
files=($dirPath/*.csv)
```

How can I make it work so the var $1 can be read as either $1.csv or $1.CSV?

Comment: Try `shopt -s nocasematch` and see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395685/bash-case-insensitive-matching-of-variable

Comment: the second example works because there is a wildcard (`*`) and  `nocaseglob` influences the way in which it will "match patterns"

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeUdosen . The shopt -s nocasematch solution works fine

Comment: Other issues aside, have you considered using a case-insensitive filesystem or directory? This [article from last year](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=EXT4-Case-Insensitive-Linux-5.2) says it's coming to Linux in kernel 5.2, and some filesystems are case-insensitive by default.

Comment: @HelloQuantumWorld : What do you want to achieve? `date=("$1".csv)` creates a one-element array named `date`, and the element is set to the first parameter, catenated with a literal `.csv`. I don't see at which point case sensitivity could come into play - it's just string catenation.

Answer (score 1):

`nocaseglob` works only for globs (i.e. `*`, `?`, `[]`).
`"$1".csv` is not a glob and therefore not affected by the setting.

You can turn your string into a glob by using a character class that matches exactly one letter:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
date=("$1".cs[v])
```

This works only because you know a literal part of your string. If you wanted do `("$1")` then you had to rely on extended globs:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -s extglob
date=("$1"?())
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
shopt -s nocasematch
```

Works.

Comment: Are you sure? The description in `man bash | grep -A5 '^ *nocasematch$'` does not sound like it would. Also, if it worked, wouldn't you then loose the ability to safely specify literal strings? How should bash know if `a=(abc)` meant the files `abc`, `ABC`, `aBc`, ... or the literal string `abc`?

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.